# Alert dialog with an arrow on button

Tags: android

can somebody explain me how to do this alert dialog with an arrow on button? Thank you.

[image: Screen]

Comment: Use https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView

Comment: Thats not what i need, but thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various cases where you can use.

I suggest you to use [this library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6713) (ShowCaseView).

It has something like an arrow for each item.

Comment: seems like good, but this library not compatability with design

Comment: These two are compatible with design: https://androidexample365.com/material-intro-view-is-a-showcase-android-library/ or https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView